# How to store the file in a string

Tags: c#

I am trying to store this file in a string.but i don know how to do it??can you
please help me.This is my program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Sample_Program_For_CC_ utility  
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{

  TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"C://Users//Darts//Desktop//sample//00004.txt");
  Console.WriteLine(tr.ReadToEnd());
  tr.Close();// 


    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: -1 for zero effort to figure it out yourself.

Comment: You already have it in a string - the argument to Console.WriteLine()

Comment: @Oded i am new to c#. thats why i don know how to do it.

Comment: Be that as it may, you didn't explain what exactly you are having problems with and what you don't understand - it makes it difficult to give you an answer that will help you understand.

Answer (score 5):

It's not really clear what's going wrong with the code you've given, but it's simpler to use [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx). For eaxmple:

```
string file = @"C:\Users\Darts\Desktop\sample\00004.txt"
string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
```

Comment: i have read the file using the stram reader method.now i must store it in a string?

Comment: @user1129403: If you're calling `ReadToEnd`, that already returns a string - just store the result in a variable...

Answer (score 3):

You could just do:

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C://Users//Darts//Desktop//sample//00004.txt");
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx

Comment: putting double slash, is not needed, as you already put "@" verbatim string to escape :)

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText( yourPathAndFile );
```

Answer (score 1):

`String theString = tr.ReadToEnd();`

As .ReadToEnd() returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ReadAllText

```
string fileContents = File.ReadAllText("c:\\filename.txt")
```

btw. you don't need @ if you are using double backslash, and you have to use backslash and not slash

Answer (score 0):

You can load the file contents in a string as follows.

```
string fileContents = tr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Will this method store my file in a string?

Comment: yes, the string fileContens will now hold the contents from the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileStream FS = new FileStream(@"C://Users//Darts//Desktop//sample//00004.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"C://Users//Darts//Desktop//sample//00004.txt"); 
  Console.WriteLine(tr.ReadToEnd()); 
  tr.Close();
```